# datediff in mysql select new field only if of certain value

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have a huge table of 2.000.000 rows in which I have two columns that are dates. Now I want to find all those rows where the difference between the two dates is > 30.
I have already set a query of this sort:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(date1, date2) as new
FROM table1;
```

and it works and list all the results and shows the difference. Now, I would like to have as a result only those cases where the difference between the two dates is higher than 30, and also have the evidence of this number.

I have tried

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(date1, date2) >30 as new
FROM table1;
```

But as a result in column new I have always value 1 (which I think stands for TRUE), but I need to see this difference (the number: 31, 32, 33 ecc.).

Can someone please help me?

thank you

Comment: Select the checkmark to the left of your accepted answer, don't simply rename the title with (CLOSED).  Selecting an answer automatically *closes* the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, try
`SELECT datediff(date1, date2) AS new FROM table1 WHERE new > 30;`

The `>` operator can be used as a boolean and is comparing your `datediff()` and your `30`.  That's why you should place it in a WHERE statement, to prevent a boolean value in your select.

Answer (score 0):

```
select datediff(date1;date2) >30 as new from table1
```

gives values: 1 because, it returns whether `datediff(date1;date2) > 30`is true or not!

Try this

---

`SELECT datediff(date1;date2) as new FROM table WHERE datediff(date1;date2) >30;`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(date1, date2) as new
FROM table1
WHERE DATEDIFF(date1, date2) > 30;
```

Comment: Thanks Olivier but returns NULL

Comment: What does it mean ? Is your resultset empty or a single row with a single NULL value ?

Comment: Hi Olivier, I wrote it down again; it works fine, thanks a lot